# A question on Random Walks and Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Suppose that $ (X_n,n \in N) $ is a Markov chain whose transition probability matrix is given by

$ P=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 1-\alpha \\1-\beta & \beta \end{bmatrix} $

(a) Deduce that $ Z_n =(X_{n-1},X_n)$ is a Markov Chain with the four states $(0,0)$ $(0,1)$ $(1,0)$ $(1,1)$

(b) Determine the transition probability matrix of $ (Z_n,n \in N) $

Comment: What are the states for $(X_n)$?

Comment: that is all i have been given

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll assume that $(X_n)$ has state space $\{0,1\}$ and is **time homogeneous**.

What you have to prove in a) is the following:
$P(Z_n=i_n|Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1},Z_{n-2}=i_{n-2}...Z_{0}=i_{0}) = P(Z_{n}=i_{n}|Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1})$, where $i_{k}$ is one of $\{(0,0), (0,1),(1,0), (1,1)\}$. This is called the Markov Property. It roughly means that the future depends only on the present, not the past.

**a)** This means that in your case, no matter what happened before the current $Z_n$, i.e. whatever the previous $Z_i$'s were, the transition probability depends only on $Z_{n}$. Try to formalize your argument for this particular case.

As for **b)** the transition probabilities $P(Z_n=i_n|Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1})$ mean what is the chance of $Z_{n}$ being equal to $i_{n}$ given $Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}$
For example if $Z_{n-1}=(0,0)$ the transition probability $P(Z_n=(0,1)|Z_{n-1}=(0,0)) = P(X_{n-1}=0, X_{n}=1| X_{n-2}=0, X_{n-1}=0) = P(X_{n}=1|X_{n-1}=0)=1 -\alpha$

Note how we used the Markov property.

You will have to end up with a 4 by 4 matrix (1 row and 1 column for each state) and if you've done it correctly the rows will have to sum up to $1$. I can be of assistance if it's not too urgent.

Comment: I came up with the transition matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 1-\alpha &0&0 \\0 & 0 &1-\beta& \beta \\ \alpha & 1-\alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1-\beta & \beta \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Looks right, but it depends how you've listed the rows and columns